# gtm-oauth2 crash on Mac OSX when authenticating with Instagram API

Tags: objective-c, macos, oauth-2.0, instagram, gtm-oauth2

I'm building a small Instagram client for personal use on Mac OSX. I'm currently using gtm-oauth2 to obtain an oauth2 token from Instagram. I'm following the guide provided with the source to obtain this token. I've got it 90% working. The webView loads with the authentication details, and I can enter my account and the permissions screen comes up asking if I would like to grant my application access. The issue I'm running into is that after authenticating, regardless of whether I "Allow" or "Cancel", the application crashes with no stack trace or additional information. The only info I get regarding the exception is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address=0x4c1)" and it appears that the thread is doing something to do with the WebCore::ResourceLoader, but it's a bunch of ASM so I've got no idea where this call is actually occurring. Perhaps I'm not calling the windowController properly? I've got my code included below.

```
- (void)signIntoInstagram {

NSURL *tokenURL =[NSURL URLWithString:kTOKENIURl];

// Set up the OAuth request

GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication
                                 authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"Instagram"
                                 tokenURL:tokenURL
                                 redirectURI:kREDIRECTURI
                                 clientID:KCLIENTID
                                 clientSecret:KCLIENTSERCRET
                                 ];

// Specify the appropriate scope string, if any, according to the service's API documentation
auth.scope = @"basic";

NSURL *authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:KAUTHURL];

// Display the authentication view
GTMOAuth2WindowController *windowController;
windowController = [GTMOAuth2WindowController controllerWithAuthentication:auth
                                                          authorizationURL:authURL
                                                          keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                            resourceBundle:nil];

// optional: display some html briefly before the sign-in page loads
NSString *html = @"<html><body><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
[windowController setInitialHTMLString:html];

[windowController signInSheetModalForWindow:_window
                                   delegate:self
                           finishedSelector:@selector(windowController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];}
```

If I insert a breakpoint within the windowController:finishedWithAuth:error: method, the application is reaching it. However, it still crashes after I run through, which to me seems like some sort of asynchronous operation causing the error. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple here; I can't imagine there is a major flaw in Google's OAuth project.

Comment: Upon further review, I was using the wrong token URL; however, it doesn't change the crash. Any ideas?

Comment: I am actually having the same issue with the Stripe OAuth process as well.

Comment: I'm quite curious whether or not this is an issue with the actual framework, or user error.

Comment: you should try enabling NSZombie to get more info out of this exc_bad_access

Comment: I had exactly the same problem by authenticating to Onedrive. NSZombie did not alert me, so I was completely blindfolded. Thanks to this post I got rid of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this on a Google group after having the same problem https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gtm-oauth/N6jlOpL9k5g/n4TdrTJyxzcJ .  There is also an issue logged for it https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/issues/detail?id=11

Basically I commented out line 331 of GTMOAuth2WindowController.m and it worked.  You can also add your vote to the issue and maybe Google will fix it.

Comment: Wow, just like that. I was hesitant to think that it was a framework issue, but low and behold. Upvoted as well so hopefully Google spots and fixes this.